# change permissions on a not writable

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

UPDATE:

I moved my question to [ask ubuntu community](https://askubuntu.com/q/1388749/1564427), but can not delete it from here... if you have an awenser, please share it on [ubuntu community](https://askubuntu.com/q/1388749/1564427) not here... Thanks

---

i want to make an change on a file but i cant do that because i have not correct permissions:

```
➜  ls -l pycharm64.vmoptions 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 427 Dec 28 18:33 pycharm64.vmoptions
```

i tried to change permisions by these two command:

```
sudo chmod a+w pycharm64.vmoptions
```

and

```
sudo chown user:user pycharm64.vmoptions
```

but in i get an erro both time:

```
Read-only file system
```

how can i make an change on my file? (honestly i dont care about the owner and groups of the file... i just want to change my file anyway)

P.S: my OS is UBUNTU

Answer (score 0):

You can change a file on read only by setting the "immutable property"

```
chattr +i [fileName]
```

If you want to revert it just change the "+" for a "-"

```
chattr -i [fileName]
```

Comment: In both cases, i get this error: `chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on pycharm64.vmoptions`

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem could be mounted as read only. You have to change first before you can write anything to it. Changing file permissions also requires writing on the filesystem.

You may be able to mount it as read write with command like:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /mount/destination/dir
```

In this command you spesify that you want to `remount` the filesystem with different options, adding the readwrite, `rw` capability.

If you successd in changing the filesystem to read write, then you should be able to change to file permissions with the commands you tried earlier.

Comment: i tried this: `sudo mount -o remount,rw $PWD` and get this error: `mount: /snap/pycharm-community/265/bin: mount point not mounted or bad option.`. is my command ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can`t edit it directly (I'm not sure about Windows).

You should edit custom settings file instead:

1. Manually

```
nano ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/pycharm64.vmoptions
```

2. or from IDE -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869.